# Hide CMD windows in .bat file? (echo off method not working)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

A command prompt still show in this code?
I saw somewhere about >nul 2>nul but i don't know where to put it?

```
@echo off
rem script1
cd C:\Users\Blah\Downloads\Script\
start script1
rem script2
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\script\
start /W  script3.exe
rem somthing
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\script\
start /W script4.exe
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** .Save your code in a batch file lets say My.bat as below:

**My.bat**:

```
@echo off
rem script1
cd C:\Users\Blah\Downloads\Script\
start script1
rem script2
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\script\
start /W  script3.exe
rem somthing
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\script\
start /W script4.exe
exit
```

**2**. Create a VBScript file lets say Master.vbs and call your My.bat file within it.

Lets assume your batch file is at C:\Test\My.bat then:

**Master.vbs**:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Test\My.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

**It'll run your batch file in  invisible/hidden mode.**

Comment: What exactly do u mean by "call my bat" using this VBscript?

Comment: Check now..I've put step-by-step process above.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the output you're seeing is from the scripts that you're calling.

Try the following (i.e.):

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\script\
start /W  script3.exe > nul 2> nul
```

The >-symbol redirects the output to a file, if that file is `nul` it is sent to the so called "null-device", meaning it is just dropped. the `2>` also redirects any error output. You should be careful about the second, because it might cause you not to see real errors that happen in your script.

Comment: I still see the cmd window, do I put > nul 2> nul after each script1,2,3?

Comment: Oh, that is something else. How do you start the script?